# Issue sending image using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, multipeer-connectivity

I've got an app that uses Multipeer Connectivity to send files between devices. On the receiving device, `didFinishReceivingResourceWithNamelocalURL` is called, but the file at the `localURL` seems to be empty. Code below:

```
func sendPhoto() {
    guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo) else { return }
    imageData.writeToURL(photoURL, atomically: true)
    // photoURL: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A2C6681-FA7C-4821-8C21-E9C3768E84EC/Documents/temp/A9081EE5-5D43-499D-8DC0-D36FEC041FE0.png"

    session.sendResourceAtURL(photoURL, withName: "image.png", toPeer: otherPeer) { 
        error in
            print(error)
    }
}

func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {
        print(error) // error is nil
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(localURL, toURL: profilePhotoURL)
            // profilePhotoURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FE5CF814-5BD4-40A9-9444-C8776F3153DC/Documents/temp/5535AACE-2C7D-4337-BBCF-8F62BC51239C.png
        } catch { print(error) }

        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: profilePhotoURL.absoluteString) // image is nil
}
```

I've also tried getting the `NSData` at `localURL`, but it ends up being `nil`.

`photo` is a `UIImage` selected from the user's photos library. Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

**More Info:**

I checked the file system on the receiving device, and the image is there. It seems something is causing the `UIImage` constructor to fail with any image received over MPC.

**Sample Project:**

I've written a small [reproducer app](https://github.com/mpdifran/MultipeerFileShare/tree/master) on GitHub. You'll need two iOS devices to test it out.

Comment: It seems like using the `sendData` command works (at least for small images) which is fine for me. But it would still be nice to know what's wrong with the resource method of sharing images. I'll update the reproducer app with code that tries both methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and for me all I had to do was convert to an NSData immediately from the local URL as such:

```
func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String,
fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    if let localData = NSData(contentsOfURL: localURL) {
        image = UIImage(data: localData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I thought I had tried this. Good to know there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What does `localURL` print as? My immediate suspicion would be you need a URL string prefixed with `file://` in order to read from the disk... This would also explain why the data from the URL is nil too.

Comment: It is `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FE5CF814-5BD4-40A9-9444-C8776F3153DC/tmp/resource.GyAEIClpxGZEfzmy`. I then copy it to the user's directory and add the `.png` suffix: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FE5CF814-5BD4-40A9-9444-C8776F3153DC/Documents/temp/5535AACE-2C7D-4337-BBCF-8F62BC51239C.png`. I'll update the question with that information.